# please help me to rephrase that my question is accepted by male only moderators

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about my Travel Stack Exchange post: [Where is female public urination common in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/where-is-female-public-urination-common-in-europe)

Please help me formulate the questions differently. Please do not change the content, it's just words.

Thank you for help

Comment: Yeah, not all moderators are male...

Comment: I rolled back your edit, (so it is now as it was before your edit) as we do not allow deleting questions asked. You got a reply and that got several upvotes, showing that others agreed with it. There is some useful advice in it, (if not much as it is a topic that does not fit in most situations.)

Comment: Please stop vandalising your posts.

Answer (score 15):

I am your female moderator and while I have not voted to close it, I fully agree with the people who voted to close.
This is an university research topic and not a travel question.
Besides, the topic is such that it is controversial and even on TSE, which has a reputation for toilet questions, it is over the line of acceptable. I do not think you can adjust your current question in such a way you get the information you seem to seek and still be within the rules of the site.

The only option I see is asking 'I go to ... and as a woman I often need to pee with haste, can I pee in the streets without breaking the law and the conventions?'
While you can ask such a question once or twice, you will get very negative reactions if you post a series of questions along these lines.
This site is not meant for research.

I am sure someone in your university can point out options to do research, it may even be that you have to go to the different areas and ask in person. As far as I know non of the Stack Exchange sites is suitable.

There are other question and answers sites, I doubt you will get useful information on any of them. Likely they will close the question as not suitable or you get troll answers.  (Yahoo!Answers and Quora come to mind, I am sure there are more.)

I can tell you the situation in the Netherlands, men nor women are allowed to pee in public and both can get away with it when in nature far from build up areas and when discrete. Peeing in a city will get you a fine if a police officer sees you.